# laravel compact data wont read in home.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel

here is my code form my controller

i9ts seem to `Image::get()` not working when I use `image::all()` then its work

```
  public function index(){
        $images = Image::get();
        return view('home', compact('images'));
    }
```

here is my home.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form action="{{route('ablum.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit</button>
       </form> 


       @foreach($images as $image)
       <p> this is image name {{$image->name}}</p>
       @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

when I navigate to the home view I get this error

```
$images is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $images }} with {{ $images ?? '' }}
```

how can I solve this ?

Comment: As it does not seem like the issue is in the code you've shown, i'm gonna ask some(maybe obvious) things since the problem is usually there where we are not looking: Are you certain you are using the correct route? Are there any other references to `$images` in other blade files which are included?

Comment: Image::all()  when I use this is work as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and rewrite your controller code like this:

```php
return view('home')->with(compact('images'));
```

Official Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-view) does not say anything about any second parameters to `view()` helper.
`with()` should actually append the data and `$images` should be available in blade now.

Also, for simplicity, just use `Image::all()`. If this again is not working, you can try and ditch the `compact` method and in `with()` send an array like:

```php
return view('home')->with(['images' => $images]);
```

Comment: I've always used the 2nd param of view() as data, it is built so you can use it like that.